# remove responsiveness from slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have a simple slideshow, only images with controllers but it is responsive, and i want to remove the responsiveness. 
So far i removed all the media queries from the style-sheet (css) and removed the meta viewport also; but the slider is still responsive, i know or at least i think i know this feature is set on the jQuery file linked to my slider but i am not sure which action i should remove or how to edit it.

This is the file:

```
(function (e) {
    e.skdslider = function (t, n) {
        var r = {
            delay: 2e3,
            animationSpeed: 500,
            showNav: true,
            autoSlide: true,
            showNextPrev: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            numericNav: false,
            showPlayButton: false,
            animationType: "fading"
        };
        if (n) {
            e.extend(r, n)
        }
        var i = "ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;
        e(t).wrap('<div class="skdslider"></div>');
        var s = e(t).closest("div.skdslider");
        s.find("ul").addClass("slides");
        var o = s.find("ul.slides li");
        var u = 0;
        r.currentSlide = 0;
        r.currentState = "pause";
        r.running = false;
        if (r.animationType == "fading") {
            o.each(function () {
                e(this).css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "0",
                    top: "0",
                    bottom: "0",
                    right: "0"
                })
            })
        }
        if (r.animationType == "sliding") {
            o.each(function () {
                e(this).css({
                    "float": "left",
                    display: "block",
                    position: "relative"
                })
            });
            var a = s.outerWidth() * o.size();
            s.find("ul.slides").css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: "0",
                width: a
            });
            o.css({
                width: s.outerWidth(),
                height: s.outerHeight()
            });
            e(window).resize(function () {
                var e = s.outerWidth() * o.size();
                s.find("ul.slides").css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "0",
                    width: e
                });
                o.css({
                    width: s.outerWidth(),
                    height: s.outerHeight()
                })
            })
        }
        e.skdslider.enableTouch(s, o, r);
        e.skdslider.createNav(s, o, r);
        o.eq(u).show();
        if (r.autoSlide == true) {
            r.currentState = "play";
            r.interval = setTimeout(function () {
                e.skdslider.playSlide(s, o, r)
            }, r.delay)
        }
        if (r.pauseOnHover == true) {
            o.hover(function () {
                if (r.autoSlide == true) {
                    r.currentState = "pause";
                    clearTimeout(r.interval)
                }
            }, function () {
                if (r.autoSlide == true) {
                    r.currentState = "play";
                    if (r.autoSlide == true) e.skdslider.playSlide(s, o, r)
                }
            })
        }
    };
    e.skdslider.createNav = function (t, n, r) {
        var s = '<ul class="slide-navs">';
        for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            var o = "";
            if (r.numericNav == true) o = i + 1;
            if (i == 0) s += '<li class="current-slide slide-nav-' + i + '"><a>' + o + "</a></li>";
            else s += '<li class="slide-nav-' + i + '"><a>' + o + "</a></li>"
        }
        s += "</ul>";
        if (r.showNav == true) {
            t.append(s);
            var u = t.find(".slide-navs")[0].offsetWidth;
            u = parseInt(u / 2);
            u = -1 * u;
            t.find(".slide-navs").css("margin-left", u);
            t.find(".slide-navs li").click(function () {
                index = t.find(".slide-navs li").index(this);
                targetSlide = index;
                clearTimeout(r.interval);
                r.currentState = "play";
                r.running = false;
                e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r, targetSlide);
                return false
            })
        }
        if (r.showNextPrev == true) {
            var a = '<a class="prev"></a>';
            a += '<a class="next"></a>';
            t.append(a);
            t.find("a.prev").click(function () {
                e.skdslider.prev(t, n, r)
            });
            t.find("a.next").click(function () {
                e.skdslider.next(t, n, r)
            })
        }
        if (r.showPlayButton == true) {
            var f = r.currentState == "play" || r.autoSlide == true ? '<a class="play-control pause"></a>' : '<a class="play-control play"></a>';
            t.append(f);
            t.hover(function () {
                t.find("a.play-control").css("display", "block")
            }, function () {
                t.find("a.play-control").css("display", "none")
            });
            t.find("a.play-control").click(function () {
                if (r.autoSlide == true) {
                    clearTimeout(r.interval);
                    r.autoSlide = false;
                    r.currentState = "pause";
                    e(this).addClass("play");
                    e(this).removeClass("pause")
                } else {
                    r.currentState = "play";
                    r.autoSlide = true;
                    e(this).addClass("pause");
                    e(this).removeClass("play");
                    if (r.currentSlide + 1 == n.length) targetSlide = 0;
                    else targetSlide = r.currentSlide + 1;
                    clearTimeout(r.interval);
                    e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r, targetSlide)
                }
                return false
            })
        }
    };
    e.skdslider.next = function (t, n, r) {
        if (r.currentSlide + 1 == n.length) targetSlide = 0;
        else targetSlide = r.currentSlide + 1;
        clearTimeout(r.interval);
        r.currentState = "play";
        e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r, targetSlide);
        return false
    };
    e.skdslider.prev = function (t, n, r) {
        if (r.currentSlide == 0) targetSlide = n.length - 1;
        else targetSlide = r.currentSlide - 1;
        clearTimeout(r.interval);
        r.currentState = "play";
        r.running = false;
        e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r, targetSlide);
        return true
    };
    e.skdslider.prev = function (t, n, r) {
        if (r.currentSlide == 0) targetSlide = n.length - 1;
        else targetSlide = r.currentSlide - 1;
        clearTimeout(r.interval);
        r.currentState = "play";
        r.running = false;
        e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r, targetSlide);
        return true
    };
    e.skdslider.playSlide = function (t, n, r, i) {
        if (r.currentState == "play" && r.running == false) {
            t.find(".slide-navs li").removeClass("current-slide");
            if (typeof i == "undefined") {
                i = r.currentSlide + 1 == n.length ? 0 : r.currentSlide + 1
            }
            if (r.animationType == "fading") {
                r.running = true;
                n.eq(r.currentSlide).fadeOut(r.animationSpeed);
                n.eq(i).fadeIn(r.animationSpeed, function () {
                    e.skdslider.removeIEFilter(e(this)[0]);
                    r.running = false
                })
            }
            if (r.animationType == "sliding") {
                var s = i * t.outerWidth() * -1;
                r.running = true;
                t.find("ul.slides").animate({
                    left: s
                }, r.animationSpeed, function () {
                    r.running = false
                })
            }
            t.find(".slide-navs li").eq(i).addClass("current-slide");
            r.currentSlide = i
        }
        if (r.autoSlide == true && r.currentState == "play") {
            r.interval = setTimeout(function () {
                e.skdslider.playSlide(t, n, r)
            }, r.delay)
        }
    };
    e.skdslider.enableTouch = function (t, n, r) {
        function a(e) {
            i = e.touches[0].pageX;
            s = e.touches[0].pageY;
            t[0].addEventListener("touchmove", f, false);
            t[0].addEventListener("touchend", l, false)
        }
        function f(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = e.touches[0].pageX;
            var n = e.touches[0].pageY;
            o = i - t;
            u = s - n
        }
        function l(i) {
            t[0].removeEventListener("touchmove", f, false);
            if (o > 0) {
                e.skdslider.next(t, n, r)
            } else {
                e.skdslider.prev(t, n, r)
            }
            t[0].removeEventListener("touchend", l, false)
        }
        t[0].addEventListener("touchstart", a, false);
        var i;
        var s;
        var o;
        var u
    };
    e.skdslider.removeIEFilter = function (e) {
        if (e.style.removeAttribute) {
            e.style.removeAttribute("filter")
        }
    };
    e.fn.skdslider = function (t) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new e.skdslider(this, t)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a `return` statement to the top of the `resize` handler within the plug-in code which will prevent it executing the code below:

```
    e(window).resize(function () {

        // don't do anything on window resize
        return;

        var e = s.outerWidth() * o.size();
        s.find("ul.slides").css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: "0",
            width: e
        });
        o.css({
            width: s.outerWidth(),
            height: s.outerHeight()
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry to bother you but i am not too familiar with jquery code  , could you tell me where to place this code?

Comment: Find the resize method in the plugin code and add a return statement to the top of the function. This will prevent it executing the resize logic.

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest getting a working example in http://jsfiddle.net and then we've got something to play around with.

Comment: Can you instantiate the plug-in in this version of your demo (I've added some placeholders) :- http://jsfiddle.net/3LLrd/1/